# (1406, "Data too long for column 'sr_number' at row 1") After receiving a post in Django and saving to DB

Tags: mysql, django, forms, post

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm fairly new to django and developing web apps in general, but up to this point i've been able to basically brute force everything or figure it out on my own; however, this has me stumped.

For some reason it appears that my code is trying to submit the entire html from my field, rather than just the data it contains, and I'm not sure why.

Error message debug shows this:

```
POST Variable       Value
submitter           u'ccroffor'
csrfmiddlewaretoken u'P8s3aL4bkyzZJWHPitQVEIFS6Lxt3s6e'
sac_id              u'892064'
sr_number           u'3-3016786463'
```

But the Query shows this:

```
    query   
'INSERT INTO `autoed_submission` (`sr_number`, `sac_id`, `submission_time`, `completed_time`, `submitter`, `submission_helpful`, `submission_link`) VALUES (\'<textarea cols=\\"40\\" id=\\"id_sr_number\\" name=\\"sr_number\\" placeholder=\\"ex... 3-3010581928\\" rows=\\"1\\">\\r\\n3-3016786463</textarea>\', \'<textarea cols=\\"40\\" id=\\"id_sac_id\\" name=\\"sac_id\\" placeholder=\\"ex... 890046, 890052, ...\\" rows=\\"1\\">\\r\\n892064</textarea>\', \'2013-04-20\', NULL, \'<textarea cols=\\"40\\" id=\\"id_submitter\\" name=\\"submitter\\" placeholder=\\"ex... ccroffor\\" rows=\\"1\\">\\r\\nccroffor</textarea>\', \'U\', \'undefined\')'
```

Views.py

```
def mySubView(request):
if request.method == 'POST':                                            #checking request
    form = AutoEdForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():                                                             #validating form
        newSubmission = Submission(sr_number = form['sr_number'], sac_id = form['sac_id'], submitter = form['submitter'], submission_time = datetime.now(tzz))  #formatting form data to db model
        newSubmission.save()    #saving data to db
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') #redirecting to thanks page
else:
    form = AutoEdForm() 
return render_to_response('submission.html', {'form':form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
class AutoEdForm(forms.Form):
sr_number = forms.CharField(
    max_length=100,
    label=u'SR Number',
    widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'ex... 3-3010581928',
            'rows': '1',
        })
)

sac_id = forms.CharField(
    max_length=100,
    label=u'Sac ID',
    widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'ex... 890046, 890052, ...',
            'rows': '1',
        })
)

submitter = forms.CharField(
    max_length=100,
    label=u'nai-corp Username',
    widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'ex... ccroffor',
            'rows': '1',
        })
)   

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(AutoEdForm, self).clean()
    return cleaned_data
```

Relavent html

```
{% load bootstrap_toolkit %}
     <div class="container well">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% include "bootstrap_toolkit/field_horizontal.html" %}
        {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:180px">           
    </form>
     </div> <!-- /container -->
```

models.py

```
class Submission(models.Model):

ED_VALUE = (
    ('A', 'Averted'),
    ('N', 'Not Averted'),
    ('U', 'Unanswered'),
)

sr_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
sac_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
submission_time = models.DateField(null=True)
completed_time = models.DateField(null=True)
submitter = models.CharField(max_length=100)
submission_helpful = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ED_VALUE, blank=False, default="U")
submission_link = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,default="undefined")
```

Comment: by the way I suggest you to look at [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save [cleaned data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data), not form fields

```
if form.is_valid():
    data = form.cleaned_data
    newSubmission = Submission(sr_number = data['sr_number'], sac_id = data['sac_id'], submitter = data['submitter'], submission_time = datetime.now(tzz))  #formatting form data to db model
```